# osql batch file error

Tags: sql-server, batch-file

I am trying to create a database from cmd. All files (.sql) are working properly and the connection to the server is also working properly..

```
set SERV= -S LENOVO\SQLEXPRESS -E 
echo Beginning...
osql %SERV% -i D:\project 300\DATA\createdb.sql -o D:\project 300\logs\createdb.log
osql %SERV% -i D:\project 300\DATA\createtables.sql -o D:\project 300\logs\createtables.log
osql %SERV% -i D:\project 300\DATA\createindex.sql -o D:\project 300\logs\createindex.log
osql %SERV% -i D:\project 300\DATA\dataentry.sql -o D:\project 300\logs\dataentry.log
echo end of batch file
pause
```

Comment: Where is the error? Have you checked the log files that your commands (should) generate?

Comment: well cmd doesnt tell you where is the error...but what do you mean about checking the log files..the log files are empty text files but with an extension .log .. am i doing it wrong ?

Comment: I am by far not an (o)sql expert, so I just wondered if any possible error message wasn't dumped in the logs. So, are you sure that the DB doesn't get created? You should check `%errorlevel%` in the batch file after each command (to rule out these kind of errors - and if necessary move the investigation to _osql_).

Comment: Before anything else, stop using `osql`. It was deprecated at least 11 years ago now (when SQL Server 2005 was released). It doesn't handle newer datatypes, etc. You need to be using `SQLCMD`. After switching to that, run one script at a time and see what happens. Also please note in the Question which version of SQL Server you are using.